# updating the UI from the handler in another Runnable

Tags: android, timer, handler

I have problem with something, which should work as a timer. I have read this article according to the using "timer" in Android:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

I have the TextView and ImageView in my layout. I have AnimationDrawable in this ImageView. I have overrided the AnimationDrawable class, because I want to know when my animation is completed. However, the runnable I want to call when my animation is ended - work properly. But in case, when I want to upadate TextView each second, another runnable (in the code below) is calling only once (I can see the number "1" during all the animation).

```
TextView timeFlow;
int seconds;

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {            
           seconds++;             
           timeFlow.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));          
       }
};

private void startAnimation() {      
    image = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image);      
    recordImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_animation);
    timeFlow = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.time_flow);
    timeFlow.setText("...");            

    image.post(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        CustomAnimationDrawable currentAnimation = new CustomAnimationDrawable((AnimationDrawable) recordImage.getBackground());
        currentAnimation.setOnFinishCallback(runnable);
        recordImage.setBackgroundDrawable(currentAnimation);
        currentAnimation.start();                               

        handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        handler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);                                          
        }
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a UI method from a worker thread.  Instead you need to change the code in mUpdateTimeTask to

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {            
         seconds++;             
         timeFlow.post(new Runnable() {
               timeFlow.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));
         });
         // It's not clear if handler is accessible here, but you get the picture.
         handler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100); 
    }
};
```

The [Worker Thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) section in the android dev guide has more examples.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to call `handler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);` at the end of your run() method.  Handler.postDelayed is a one-time shot.  I'll edit my response to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you, it really works. But I have one problem yet. My animation has completed, the runnable - AnimationDrawable OnFinishCallback - has been called, but the "timer" is still working. I think it should stop when my animation has stopped.

Comment: Oh it was so easy, oncly to use `handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);` in the runnable called after AnimationDrawable finish.